# What is function of this sequence on to natural numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1,2,4,3,6,5,10,7,14,8,16,9,18,11,22,12,24,13,26,15,30,17,34,19,38,20,40,21,42,23,46,25,50,...$

such that we begin from $1$ and then write $2$ then $2\times2$ then $3$ then $2\times3$ then ... but if $n$ is even and previously we have written $0.5n$ and then $n$ then ignore $n$ and continue and write $n+1$ and then $2n+2$ and so on for example we have $1,2,4,3,6,5,10$ so after $10$ we should write $7,14,...$ because previously we have written $3,6$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck

Comment: @tienlee I need it for [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)!

Comment: [OEISA034701](http://oeis.org/A034701): "a(n) is the smallest number not of the form a(i) (1<=i<=n-1) or a(i)+a(n-1) (1<=i<=n-2)".

Comment: @r.e.s. thank you! (but it isn't a function) hasn't been defined its function?

Comment: The quoted phrase *is* the definition.

Comment: @r.e.s. but it is a recurrence relation! **I don't like it!**

Comment: In other words, you're asking "How can this sequence be defined without using recursion?"

Comment: @r.e.s. yes, that's right! (though I hadn't checked it in OEIS)

Comment: @r.e.s. so seemly (unfortunately) the answer is **not defined yet!** anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a definition of your sequence without using recursion.

Let $S=(S_0,S_1,S_2,\ldots)$ be the increasing sequence of positive integers that are expressible as either $2^e$ or as $o_1\cdot 2^{o_2}$, where $e$ is an even nonnegative integer, $o_1>1$ is an odd positive integer and $o_2$ is an odd positive integer. Thus $$S=(1, 4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 18, 22, 24, 26, 30, 34, 38, 40,42,\ldots).$$ Let $\bar{S}$ be the complement of $S$ with respect to the positive integers; i.e., $$\bar{S}=(2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25,\ldots).$$ Your sequence is then $T=(T_0,T_1,T_2,\ldots)$, where
$$T_n:=\begin{cases}S_{n\over 2}&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\
\bar{S}_{n-1\over 2}&\text{ if $n$ is odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $T=(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 10, 7, 14, 8, 16, 9, 18, 11, 22, 12, 24, 13, 26, 15, 30, 17, 34, 19, 38, 20, \ldots).$

---

References:

Sequences $S,\bar{S},T$ are OEIS [A171945](http://oeis.org/A171945), [A053661](http://oeis.org/A053661), [A034701](http://oeis.org/A034701) respectively. These are all discussed in ["The vile, dopey, evil and odious game players"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X11001427).

---

Sage code:

```
def is_in_S(n): return ( (n.valuation(2) % 2 == 0) and (n.is_power_of(2))  ) or ( (n.valuation(2) % 2 == 1) and not(n.is_power_of(2))  )
S = [n for n in [1..50] if is_in_S(n)]
S_ = [n for n in [1..50] if not is_in_S(n)]
T = []
for i in range(max(len(S),len(S_))):
    if i % 2 == 0: T += [S[i/2]]
    else: T += [S_[(i-1)/2]]
print S
print S_
print T

[1, 4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 18, 22, 24, 26, 30, 34, 38, 40, 42, 46, 50]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 41, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49]
[1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 10, 7, 14, 8, 16, 9, 18, 11, 22, 12, 24, 13, 26, 15, 30, 17, 34, 19, 38, 20, 40, 21, 42, 23, 46, 25, 50]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! you are great!